# ion-input name attribute not recognised in ngForm

Tags: angular, validation, ionic-framework

I am getting a runtime error on an ionic form where I want to do validation. I have tried the strategy of adding a name attribute to each input control but the error is raised:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or ...

Similar code worked before in a similar task: Can anyone spot my error, please?

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ enquiry.name || 'New Enquiry'}}</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="onSave()">
          <ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons> 
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <form #formValues="ngForm">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="enquiry.date" name="date"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="enquiry.name" name="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Phone</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="enquiry.phone" name="phone"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Type</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="enquiry.type">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let type of types" name="type">{{type}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Budget</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="enquiry.budget" name="budget"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="enquiry.type">
```

is missing  the name attribute.